# Invalid client error getting when trying to get new access token using refresh token in spring oauth2

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0

**when I am hit url to get access token as well as refresh token it works fine.**

```
url:- http://localhost:8080/thela-web/oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=thelaapp&client_secret=thelaapp&username=8527886649&password=Pkc12345@
```

**Response is perfect**

```
{
    "access_token": "6ae54dc4-3dbf-48e6-9b7a-d58ececd48df",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "refresh_token": "7c752534-0945-464d-b6d3-2027205630f3",
    "expires_in": 1799,
    "scope": "read write trust"
}
```

**But I am trying to get the access token using refresh token in spring it gives an error.**

```
url:-http://localhost:8080/thela-web/oauth/token?grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=7c752534-0945-464d-b6d3-2027205630f3
```

**I am getting respose like**

```
{
    "error": "invalid_client",
    "error_description": "Bad client credentials"
}
```

Authorisation Server configuration class.

```
package com.endowment.thela.oauth2.configuration;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.configurers.ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableAuthorizationServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.UserApprovalHandler;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore;

import com.endowment.thela.webapp.constatnt.SecurityConstatnt;

@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter{


    private static final String GRANT_TYPE_PASSWORD="password";
    private static final String GRANT_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION_CODE="authorization_code";
    private static final String GRANT_TYPE_REFRESH_TOKEN="refresh_token";
    private static final String GRANT_TYPE_IMPLICIT="implicit";
    private static final String AUTHORITY_ROLE_CLIENT="ROLE_CLIENT";
    private static final String AUTHORITY_ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT="ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT";
    private static final String SCOPE_READ="read";
    private static final String SCOPE_WRITE="write";
    private static final String SCOPE_TRUST="trust";

    @Value("${oauth2.client_id}")
    private String clientId;

    @Value("${oauth2.client_secret}")
    private String clientSecret;

    @Value("${oauth2.access_token.validity_second}")
    private int accessTokenValiditySeconds;

    @Value("${oauth2.refresh_token.validity_second}")
    private int refreshTokenValiditySeconds;

    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Autowired
    private UserApprovalHandler userApprovalHandler;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory().withClient(clientId)
            .authorizedGrantTypes(GRANT_TYPE_PASSWORD, GRANT_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION_CODE, GRANT_TYPE_REFRESH_TOKEN, GRANT_TYPE_IMPLICIT)
            .authorities(AUTHORITY_ROLE_CLIENT, AUTHORITY_ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT)
            .scopes(SCOPE_READ, SCOPE_WRITE, SCOPE_TRUST)
            .secret(clientSecret)
            .accessTokenValiditySeconds(accessTokenValiditySeconds).
            refreshTokenValiditySeconds(refreshTokenValiditySeconds);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore).userApprovalHandler(userApprovalHandler)
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
        oauthServer.realm(SecurityConstatnt.REALM).allowFormAuthenticationForClients();
    }

}
```

logs:

```
2018-03-02 22:51:47 DEBUG OrRequestMatcher:65 - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/oauth/token']
2018-03-02 22:51:47 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:151 - Checking match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/oauth/token'
2018-03-02 22:51:47 DEBUG OrRequestMatcher:68 - matched
2018-03-02 22:51:47 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:324 - /oauth/token?grant_type=refresh_token&client_id=thelaaap&client_secret=thelaaap&refresh_token=7a7916a3-4087-42fe-8b7e-7addaacf7bee at position 1 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2018-03-02 22:51:47 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:324 - /oauth/token?grant_type=refresh_token&client_id=thelaaap&client_secret=thelaaap&refresh_token=7a7916a3-4087-42fe-8b7e-7addaacf7bee at position 2 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2018-03-02 22:51:47 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:324 - /oauth/token?grant_type=refresh_token&client_id=thelaaap&client_secret=thelaaap&refresh_token=7a7916a3-4087-42fe-8b7e-7addaacf7bee at position 3 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2018-03-02 22:51:47 DEBUG HstsHeaderWriter:128 - Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@1690ba43
2018-03-02 22:51:47 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:324 - /oauth/token?grant_type=refresh_token&client_id=thelaaap&client_secret=thelaaap&refresh_token=7a7916a3-4087-42fe-8b7e-7addaacf7bee at position 4 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2018-03-02 22:51:47 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:151 - Checking match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/logout'
2018-03-02 22:51:47 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:324 - /oauth/token?grant_type=refresh_token&client_id=thelaaap&client_secret=thelaaap&refresh_token=7a7916a3-4087-42fe-8b7e-7addaacf7bee at position 5 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter'
2018-03-02 22:51:47 DEBUG ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter:211 - Request is to process authentication
2018-03-02 22:51:47 DEBUG ProviderManager:162 - Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider
2018-03-02 22:51:47 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:251 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'scopedTarget.clientDetailsService'
2018-03-02 22:51:47 DEBUG DaoAuthenticationProvider:147 - User 'thelaaap' not found
2018-03-02 22:51:47 DEBUG ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter:350 - Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials
2018-03-02 22:51:47 DEBUG ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter:351 - Updated SecurityContextHolder to contain null Authentication
2018-03-02 22:51:47 DEBUG ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter:352 - Delegating to authentication failure handler org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter$1@660768ca
2018-03-02 22:51:47 DEBUG DefaultOAuth2ExceptionRenderer:101 - Written [error="invalid_client", error_description="Bad client credentials"] as "application/json;charset=UTF-8" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@6e9cd080]
2018-03-02 22:51:47 DEBUG SecurityContextPersistenceFilter:105 - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Then how can i solve this problem, please provide the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your client should have refresh_token registered as a grantType

Also did you pass clientid and secret as base64 encoded authorization header?

```
curl -v -X POST \

   -H "Content-Type: application/json" \

   -H "Authorization: Basic MzUzYjMwMmM0NDU3NGY1NjUwNDU2ODdlNTM0ZTdkNmE6Mjg2OTI0Njk3ZTYxNWE2NzJhNjQ2YTQ5MzU0NTY0NmM=" \

   'http://localhost:8080/test/oauth/token?grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=xxxxxx'
```

UPDATED:

The answer seems to be with this line

```
2018-03-02 22:51:47 DEBUG DaoAuthenticationProvider:147 - User 'thelaaap' not found
```

Probably the user is deleted and therefore the app cannot grant the refresh_token

Comment: yes I have registered grantType but i am getting same

Comment: clients.inMemory().withClient(clientId)
            .authorizedGrantTypes(GRANT_TYPE_PASSWORD, GRANT_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION_CODE, GRANT_TYPE_REFRESH_TOKEN, GRANT_TYPE_IMPLICIT)
            .authorities(AUTHORITY_ROLE_CLIENT, AUTHORITY_ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT)
            .scopes(SCOPE_READ, SCOPE_WRITE, SCOPE_TRUST)
            .secret(clientSecret)
            .accessTokenValiditySeconds(accessTokenValiditySeconds).
            refreshTokenValiditySeconds(refreshTokenValiditySeconds);

Comment: Can you show me your authorization server config class?

Comment: Check my updated answer. did you send the client id and secret in authorization header?

Comment: Add this in application.properties logging.level.org.springframework=DEBUG

and run it again, and show me the stack trace please.

Comment: Please check I have added log

Comment: It says that User 'thelaaap' not found. Can you check that you have this user? Is it inmemory??

Comment: how can i check this?

Comment: Can you upload the code to github? and I can show u

Comment: can u download from bitbucket

Comment: Yes i can if you give me the link